# What are the possible consequences of clicking a link in a phishing mail?

Tags: phishing

I clicked on a Google Slides spoof link in an email in Yahoo mail in a Chrome browser.
As soon as I had clicked it I realized my mistake. I did not enter any password or give away info.
What are the possible consequences of such an attack? How do I proceed from here?
Are there logs I can inspect to find out what the code on that webpage did?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What malicious things can happen when clicking on links in email?](/questions/3674), [Why is a link in an email more dangerous than a link from a web search?](/questions/241139), [Accidentally clicked a phishing link, am I at risk?](/questions/200736).

Answer (score 0):

1. *What are the possible consequences of such an attack?*

As long as you don't provide/download anything in/from phishing link, risk of consequences is extremely low.

2. *How do I proceed from here?*

If the email you received was generic phishing and you weren't targeted directly, I would not take any action.

3. *Are there logs I can inspect to find out what the code on that webpage did?*

I'd recommend checking url in https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url and see if there is some information about "chrome CVE" in "Details" or "Community".

Further reading:
https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/three-vulnerabilities-in-chrome/42265/

Comment: Clicking links in a phishing email can do extraordinary damage. Reporting emails as phishing is a great thing to do instead of "nothing". Virustotal can give very limited results. The better option is to open the URL in a malware analysis sandbox, like cuckoo.ee.